# dynamic drop down feature for sql server with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I made some progress.  My connection string has been tested and works with my sql server database.

The "dynamic" drop down feature still does not appear when I tried typing different characters for people's first names.Here is the back end code of what should work but I do not know why it is not working?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SKYNET-1000\\SQLEXPRESS;InitialCatalog=CSC_480;Integrated Security=True"); 

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String str = "select * from People where (First_Name like '%' + @search + '%')";
        SqlCommand win7 = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        win7.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

        con.Open();
        win7.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = win7;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "First_Name");
        GridView2.DataSource = ds;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

That being said everything compiles and works.  Although my other question is I have three more columns `Last_Name`, `Age` and `Gender`.

How would I put everything all together without deleting `First_Name` and only putting one column instead of putting everything together in the code above?

For example, you can only search a user by their `First_Name`, but I want to include `Last_Name`, `Age` and `Gender` into the code rather than manually deleting one option and putting the other one in.  I want to have everything in there so that way it would be searchable.

In a nutshell I'm looking for two things:

1. The code above is right but do not know why it is not performing a dynamic drop down list like google or any website that has that feature
2. Any quick tip how to write a SQL query not for one column but for all four columns like `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Age` & `Gender`?

**EDIT :**
[image]

[image]

I'm only searching by "First_Name" characters only. If I were to search for "Last_Name", "Gender" or "Age" it wouldn't work unless I deleted the First_Name column from the code and replaced it with a new column name.

That is why I am asking is there any way I could include all four columns in the code above to ensure everything would be searchable?

And this is what I mean by 'dynamic'. http://kmplot.com/analysis/index.php?p=service&cancer=ovar The link above better illustrates.

You randomly start typing characters in the "Affy id/Gene symbol" textbox and receive an unlimited options of sequences to choose from. This is where I'm stuck and need to implement this type of method into my project.

Thanks!

Comment: Which control you are using to make dynamic dropdown list?

Comment: How the code can be right if it is not working?

Comment: It will display the persons name along with the gridview when I click on the "Search button".  What I meant is that it is not functioning as a 'dynamic' drop down feature.

Comment: Please try to put some snapshot of your web application.

Answer (score 0):

> The code above is right but do not know why it is not performing a
>   dynamic drop down list like google or any website that has that
>   feature

First of all you have written your code in button click event.

So it will not work until the button 1 is pressed.

So how it is called dynamic?

To make it dynamic you have to write your code in control in which you want to put that functionality.

**For example TextChanged event.**

You have to make your controls autopostback propery = true

```
AutoPostBack=True
```

Select your control and take a look in properties window, then move you code in appropriate event in your control.

---

**EDIT :**

So as per your edit i think you want the SQL query that will work for your code.

I think it should be like that.

```
String str = "select * from People where (First_Name like '%' or Last_Name like '%' or Gender like '%' or Age like '%')";
```

I have not tested my query but i am damn sure it should be something like that, but not exactly same.

Please check it out.

I think it will work proper for First_Name and Last_Name but you may have to do some change for Gender and Age.

Please first Check it out for First_Name and Last_Name.